# SP13: Image behind Table (HTML)

Tags: 2013, css, content-editor-web-part, html

I have content editor web part that I have applied html for a table.  I would like to upload an image (through HTML script), but I want the image to appear behind the table. I tried using the following code to add the image behind the table, but the image did not appear.

```
<table align="center" style="width: 94%; height: 96%, background="myimage.gif">
```

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.  Can anyone help me with the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below css code for background image:

```
 background-image: url("Image.jpg");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:top;
 background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload your image "myimage.gif" to any document library then right click on image name in document library and get its url.
Paste this url in background property.